# how to catch url being sent back to webview (XAML/C#) on windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, webview, winrt-xaml

I am trying to detect the url that is being sent back by this url when it is being played by a webview, however I am unable to find how to do this.

The app is recieving dmevent urls and i want to be able to catch them, does anyone have any idea how to do that?

here is my code:

```
XAML: 
 <WebView x:Name="DmWebView"  
                         Width="600" Height="300"
                    />

c#:
  DmWebView.Source = new Uri("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x285bo8?html=1&controls=1&autoplay=1&api=location");
```

Windows message I am getting in the simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I to answer my old question, the only way for your JavaScript to be able to communicate with your XAML WebView correctly all of the events that are fired from your JavaScript side must be warped in this: window.external.notify("your value");  This is the only way that I have found to resolve this issue.